# How to do arithmetic operation in Firebase data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure is:

```
{
"Received":{
  "Gokul":{
     "5-2021":{"amount":"5000"},
     "6-2021":{"amount":"8000"}
  }
},
"Remaining":{
  "Gokul":{
     "5-2021":{"rem_Amount":"3000"},
     "6-2021":{"rem_Amount":"4000"}
  }
 }
}
```

In this I need to add my contribution amounts 5000+8000 = 13000 and remaining amount 3000+4000=7000 and need to subtract remaining from contribution and to set it on a Text View. In this I achieved addition operations but can't able to do subtraction. My code is,

```
 reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Received").child("Gokul");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value = snap.child("amount").getValue(String.class);
                tot = tot + Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
            amount1.setText(String.valueOf(tot));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Remaining").child("Gokul");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value = snap.child("rem_Amount").getValue(String.class);
                rem = rem + Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
            amount2.setText(String.valueOf(rem));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

avl = tot - rem;
amount3.setText(String.valueOf(avl));
```

In this when I try to get tot and rem values it gives me 0. Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Firebase, you need to remember that your code is asynchronous.

```
Integer tot = 0;
Integer rem = 0;
Integer avl = 0;
DatabaseReference reference;

reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Received").child("Gokul");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
});

reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Remaining").child("Gokul");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
});

avl = tot - rem; // this line runs before any of onDataChange/onCancelled handlers above
amount3.setText(String.valueOf(avl));
```

Next, don't reuse `reference` like you have. Store them as separate variables so you don't confuse yourself or anyone else who works with that code.

```
DatabaseReference receivedGokulRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Received").child("Gokul");
DatabaseReference remainingGokulRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Remaining").child("Gokul");
```

Next, you need to make sure that both `receivedGokulRef` and `remainingGokulRef` get their data first before calculating the balance.

**If you are expecting this `avl` value to get realtime updates**, inside of the listeners you add using the [`Query#addValueEventListener()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) method, update their respective `amount1` and `amount2` values and then call a refresh/recalculate method for `amount3`.

```
amount3.setText("Loading...");

DatabaseReference receivedGokulRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Received").child("Gokul");
receivedGokulRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Integer value = snap.child("amount").getValue(Integer.class);
            sum += value;
        }
        amount1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        refreshAvaliableBalance(); // <-- trigger calculation
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

DatabaseReference remainingGokulRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Remaining").child("Gokul");
remainingGokulRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Integer value = snap.child("amount").getValue(Integer.class);
            sum += value;
        }
        amount2.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        refreshAvaliableBalance(); // <-- trigger calculation
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

/* as a method of DetailsActivity */
private void refreshAvaliableBalance() {
    String amount1Text = amount1.getText();
    String amount2Text = amount2.getText();
    
    if (amount1Text == "" || amount2Text == "") {
        // still loading
        amount3.setText("Loading...");
        return;
    }
    
    Integer receivedSum = Integer.parseInt(amount1Text);
    Integer remainingSum = Integer.parseInt(amount2Text);
    
    Integer available = receivedSum - remainingSum;
    
    amount3.setText(String.valueOf(available));
}
```

**If you are only retrieving the balance once** you could use [`Query#get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#get()) which returns a [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) containing your data. You can then combine this with the [`Tasks`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) utility methods, you can chain actions together.

For `receivedGokulRef`, get its value and sum it together. For `remainingGokulRef`, get its value and sum it together. Once we have both sums, calculate the difference.

```
Task<Integer> receivedGokulSumTask = receivedGokulRef.get()
    .onSuccessTask(new SuccessContinuation<DataSnapshot, Integer>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Task<Integer> then(DataSnapshot querySnapshot) {
            Integer sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot childSnap : querySnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Integer value = snap.child("amount").getValue(Integer.class);
                sum += value;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    });

Task<Integer> remainingGokulSumTask = remainingGokulRef.get()
    .onSuccessTask(new SuccessContinuation<DataSnapshot, Integer>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Task<Integer> then(DataSnapshot querySnapshot) {
            Integer sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot childSnap : querySnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Integer value = snap.child("amount").getValue(Integer.class);
                sum += value;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    });

Tasks.whenAllComplete([receivedGokulSumTask, remainingGokulSumTask])
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Task<Integer>>>() {
        // Tasks.whenAllComplete never fails, so we can use addOnSuccessListener for simplicity
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Task<Integer>> sumTasks) {
            Task<Integer> receivedSumTask = sumTasks.get(0);
            Task<Integer> remainingSumTask = sumTasks.get(1);

            if (receivedSumTask.isSuccessful() && remainingSumTask.isSuccessful()) {
                // got data properly

                Integer receivedSum = receivedSumTask.getResult();
                Integer remainingSum = remainingSumTask.getResult();
                Integer available = receivedSum - remainingSum; // throw error when negative?

                amount1.setText(String.valueOf(receivedSum)); // TODO: rename amount1,amount2,amount3
                amount2.setText(String.valueOf(remainingSum));
                amount3.setText(String.valueOf(available));

                return; // done
            }

            // if here, either or both tasks failed.
            Exception receivedSumException = receivedSumTask.getException();
            Exception remainingSumException = remainingSumTask.getException();

            StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder("Error(s) fetching data");
            if (receivedSumException !== null) {
                messageBuilder.append("; Error while getting received total sum: " + receivedSumException.getMessage());
            }
            if (remainingSumException !== null) {
                messageBuilder.append("; Error while getting remaining total sum: " + receivedSumException.getMessage());
            }
            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, messageBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. While this data is being loaded, your main code continues to execute. This means that in your code the `avl = tot - rem` runs before any of the `onDataChange` methods has run, so `tot` and `rem` are still `0`.

For this reason, any code that needs the data from the database needs to be **inside** the `onDataChange`, or be called from there. Since you have two calls to load data, you'll typically want to nest those calls, and the put the calculation into the inner `onDataChange`, like this:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Received").child("Gokul");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value = snap.child("amount").getValue(String.class);
            tot = tot + Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        amount1.setText(String.valueOf(tot));

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Remaining").child("Gokul");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String value = snap.child("rem_Amount").getValue(String.class);
                    rem = rem + Integer.parseInt(value);
                }
                amount2.setText(String.valueOf(rem));

                avl = tot - rem;
                amount3.setText(String.valueOf(avl));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I recommend reading some more on this asynchronous loading, as it's a quite common stumbling block:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: Pretty sure nesting the reference and listener for `Remaining/Gokul` here is going to lead to a new listener being added each time `Received/Gokul` or its children get an update as there is no clean-up taking place.

Comment: Fair point, although I don't think OP was stuck with that just yet. ;-)    I changed it to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.